# How to keep a 2D Object 'attached' to another 2D object relative to its rotation?

Tags: 2d

I don't know how to explain this in the title, i'm new here, so hi, and sorry for any mistake I did.

Say I had two squares, Square 1 and Square 2, in my case,

Square 1 is rotating, it's pointing relative to the mouse's 2D Position.
X,Y=x1-x2,y1-y2 deg(atan2(Y,X)).

Square 2 is just 1 pixel, positioned at the top edge side of the Square 1.

How would I make it so Square 2 will always be at the top edge side relative to the rotation, like, it's 'attached' to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parent, child hierarchy, set the smaller square object as a child of the bigger square, define in your code that whatever transformation is done to parent, childs shall be affected by them.

As for the transformation itself, find the center of parent, radius to child, rotate using that data (rotate the origin, rotate the square and place it on the new origin). Alternatively if the small square is always on the same relative position, use a single image for both squares that way your first rotation will rotate both.